# How to get the small dialogue box or a chat like box when i click the image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small web page. My requirement is I want to place a image to the right side bottom corner of the webpage and when i clicked that image it should open a website or even a small dialogue box or  chat like box in that page itself. Iframes should not be used. I want to do this with script tag(script-embedding). Can anybody help me with the code.

This is my HTML code for image

```
<div class="corner">
 <img src="images/Happiest_Minds_New_Logo.jpg" alt="" class="right-corner" width="100px" height="70px">
 </div>
```

This is css for the image

```
.right-corner {
  position:fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  right:0px;
}
```

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup_chat.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom attributes like data-href to store the link and then use `window.location.href` to set the url (use `window.open` method to open link in new tab )

See example =>

**HTML**

```
<div class="corner">
 <img data-href="https://example.com" src="images/Happiest_Minds_New_Logo.jpg" alt="" class="right-corner" width="100px" height="70px">
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
 // selecting all elements with data-href attribute
 const hrefs =  document.querySelectorAll('[data-href]')
 
 // adding click event Listener
 hrefs.forEach(linkedItem =>{
   linkedItem.onclick = function (e){
     // custom code to run on event
    window.location.href =   e.target.getAttribute("data-href")
   }
 })
```

Comment: @Rohit kumar Incase of modals you can Checkout it on Google there a lot of examples which can really be helpful ! Also does this answers your question ?

Comment: Yeah it is working but i want to open that url in the same page in a small container without using iframe, object or embed tags. Is that possible to do that?

Comment: @Rohit kumar Actually that's possible ! You need to use ajax for this and a little bit of CSS .... But I recommend using iframe as it was built for this purpose only

Comment: Well i cannot use iframe for this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
popupWhatsApp = () => {
  
  let btnClosePopup = document.querySelector('.closePopup');
  let btnOpenPopup = document.querySelector('.whatsapp-button');
  let popup = document.querySelector('.popup-whatsapp');
  let sendBtn = document.getElementById('send-btn');

  btnClosePopup.addEventListener("click",  () => {
    popup.classList.toggle('is-active-whatsapp-popup')
  })
  
  btnOpenPopup.addEventListener("click",  () => {
    popup.classList.toggle('is-active-whatsapp-popup')
     popup.style.animation = "fadeIn .6s 0.0s both";
  })
  
  sendBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let msg = document.getElementById('whats-in').value;
  let relmsg = msg.replace(/ /g,"%20");
    //just change the numbers "1515551234567" for your number. Don't use +001-(555)1234567     
   window.open('https://wa.me/15551234567?text='+relmsg, '_blank'); 
  
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    popup.classList.toggle('is-active-whatsapp-popup');
  }, 3000);
}

popupWhatsApp();
```

```css
 @keyframes pulse {
        0% {
            transform: scale(1, 1);
        }

        50% {
            opacity: 0.3;
        }

        100% {
            transform: scale(1.45);
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }

    .pulse {
        -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
        animation-name: pulse;
    }

    .nav-bottom {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-content: flex-end;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 8;
        bottom: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 360px) {
        .nav-bottom {
            width: 320px;
        }
    }

    .whatsapp-button {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: center;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        z-index: 8;
        transition: 0.3s;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 7px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: white;
        /* offset-x > | offset-y ^| blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
    }

    .circle-anime {
        display: flex;
        position: absolute;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: center;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        top: 15px;
        right: 15px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        transition: 0.3s;
        background-color: #77bb4a;
        animation: pulse 1.2s 4s ease 4;
    }

    .popup-whatsapp {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: flex-start;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px;
        bottom: 85px;
        right: 6px;
        transition: 0.5s;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: white;
        /* offset-x > | offset-y ^| blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
        -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
        box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
        animation: slideInRight 0.6s 0s both;
    }

    .popup-whatsapp>div {
        margin: 5px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 680px) {
        .popup-whatsapp p {
            font-size: 0.9em;
        }
    }

    .popup-whatsapp>.content-whatsapp.-top {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .popup-whatsapp>.content-whatsapp.-top p {
        color: #585858;
        font-family: "Roboto";
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    .popup-whatsapp>.content-whatsapp.-bottom {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .closePopup {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 28px;
        height: 28px;
        margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #f76060;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
    }

    .closePopup:hover {
        background-color: #f71d1d;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .send-msPopup {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
    }

    .send-msPopup:hover {
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .is-active-whatsapp-popup {
        display: flex;
        animation: slideInRight 0.6s 0s both;
    }

    input.whats-input[type=text] {
        width: 250px;
        height: 40px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 0px solid #ffffff;
        border-radius: 20px;
        font-size: 1em;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
        outline: none;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    @media (max-width: 420px) {
        input.whats-input[type=text] {
            width: 225px;
        }
    }

    input.whats-input::placeholder {
        /* Most modern browsers support this now. */
        color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    input.whats-input[type=text]:focus {
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .icon-whatsapp-small {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
    }

    .icon-whatsapp {
        width: 45px;
        height: 45px;
    }

    .icon-font-color {
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .icon-font-color--black {
        color: #333333;
    }
```

```html
<div class="nav-bottom">
    <div class="popup-whatsapp fadeIn">
        <div class="content-whatsapp -top"><button type="button" class="closePopup">
                <i class="material-icons icon-font-color">close</i>
            </button>
            <p>Hello,  need help?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content-whatsapp -bottom">
            <input class="whats-input" id="whats-in" type="text" Placeholder="Send message..." />
            <button class="send-msPopup" id="send-btn" type="button">
                <i class="material-icons icon-font-color--black">send</i>
            </button>

        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="whats-openPopup" class="whatsapp-button">
        <img class="icon-whatsapp" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/134/134937.svg">
    </button>
    <div class="circle-anime"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

the simplest solution to use (its not customizable) is alert, confirm or prompt:

```
<div class="corner">
 <img src="images/Happiest_Minds_New_Logo.jpg" alt="" class="right-corner" width="100px" height="70px" onclick="alert('hi')">
</div>

<div class="corner">
 <img src="images/Happiest_Minds_New_Logo.jpg" alt="" class="right-corner" width="100px" height="70px" onclick="confirm('are you sure?')">
</div>

<div class="corner">
 <img src="images/Happiest_Minds_New_Logo.jpg" alt="" class="right-corner" width="100px" height="70px" onclick="prompt('enter your name', 'default name')">
</div>
```